# Need to aggregate data in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Below is the data set

[image: DataSet]

I want to merge the data set based on " UUID" to get one row with start and end time as first of start time and end of end time
All other numeric row to be summed up

Comment: It is always convenient to provide expected outcome, so that community members have clear idea what you want.

Comment: To have good idea about how to post a question, go through this  [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
        'trip_creation_time':['37:08.9', '37:08.9', '37:08.9'],
        'UUID':['ABC-1', 'ABC-1', 'ABC-1'],
        'RouteType':['C', 'C', 'C'],
        'tripid':['trip-15', 'trip-15', 'trip-15'],
        'sourcecenter':['AAC', 'AAC', 'AAC'],
        'source_name': ['H_TS_1', 'H_TS_2', 'H_TS_3'],
        'destination_center': ['AAC', 'AAC', 'AAA'],
        'destination_name': ['M-TS_1', 'M-TS_2', 'M-TS_3'],
        'starttime':['05:52.6', '05:52.6', '05:34.8'],
        'endtime':['05:34.8', '05:34.8', '35:54.0'],
        'endtoend_time': [59, 59, 210],
        'actualdistance': [9.684842238, 14.85920056, 9.499885115],
        'actualtime':[14, 30, 165],
        'otime':[8, 12, 14],
        'distance':[10.3638, 16.0049, 14.4597]
        
    })
```

Group By UUID and aggregate the columns by passing the function you want to run on each column

first of starttime and last of endtime and summing up column distance and otime

```
df.groupby('UUID').agg(starttime_first=('starttime','first'),
                      endtime_last=('starttime','last'),
                      distance_sum = ('distance', 'sum'),
                      otime_sum = ('otime', 'sum'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks …will try and update the comment

Comment: @AbhinandanKumar Please upvote if this has helped.